# How to autowire @service class ? No qualifying bean of type found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-annotations

What are the prerequisites to auto-wired any class without implementing any interface?

Class Diagrams

1. MainClass -> Annotation used : `@SpringBootApplication @EnableTransactionalManagement`
2. DatabaseConfig -> `@Configuration @EnableTransactionalManagement`
3. UserRepository -> `@Repository`
4. UserService -> `@Service` and `@Autowired UserRepository`

When I am writing test class with `@Autowired userRepository` it is working, but when I use `@Autowired UserService` and trying to call `userRepository` methods.

I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [sm.services.AgendaService] found for dependency:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHiOX.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your project/class/package structure?

Comment: @SanjayRawat added ! . Please check.

Comment: check your class sm.services.AgendaService. It seems it is missing annotation.

Comment: @Service public class AgendaServices, What else is required ?. I am not using any interface.

Comment: Is your code properly structured for AutoConfiguration? See this link - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html for more info. Also you can explicitly add packages to scan `@ComponentScan({"com.example.mybootapp","com.example.services","com.example.repo"})`

Comment: @Vishakha in case you are still looking check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35779188/5702727. I still didn't understand your project structure, thats why I didn't answer your question. If that answer doesn't solve your problem please post the structure of your app like the one in above ans. Also is this a Spring-boot app?

Answer (score 0):

I was implementing an extra interface in "public class UserService **implements SomeClass**", when i switch to interface to abstract class SomeClass its start working.

**public class UserService extends SomeClass**

Comment: If you implement an interface you have to autowire the interface and provide a qualifier for the bean.