# Spring @ComponentScan("com.junk") allows autowiring to work?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple Spring Boot Java application and it is using @Autowired.

Unless I add in the @ComponentScan annotation I get :`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` failures at run time.

Weirdly **any** [@ComponentScan](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) fixes the wiring, even if it's referring to a non-existent package.

Shouldn't @ComponentScan required valid package as an argument ?

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
// @ComponentScan // This one causes auto-wired problems. See below.
@ComponentScan("com.junk.foo") // This one works?

public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**EDIT in response to questions in comments ...**

By autowire problems I mean with `@ComponentScan` or without that annotation I get ...

```
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.foo.Foo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        ... 25 more
```

whereas if I use `@ComponentScan("com.junk.foo")` I get no auto-wire problems.

The error is :

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.2.RELEASE)


// SNIP FOR BREVITY

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'barService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is  

// SNIP FOR BREVITY

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.foo.Foo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 25 more
```

My project is like this ...

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       ├── bar
        │       │   └── BarService.java
        │       ├── example
        │       │   └── demo
        │       │       └── DemoApplication.java
        │       └── foo
        │           └── Foo.java
        └── resources
```

Comment: Can you post a class where you put @Autowired annotation and your project structure?

Comment: What do you mean by "works"?  @ComponentScan is a syntax error.  You need to either specify a package name or a class name.  The class name is a better choice because it has to really exist.  Your com.junk.foo will satistfy the syntax requirement of the Annotation, but it won't help get things Autowired.

Comment: Actually `@ComponentScan` is a valid annotation and not a syntax error.
`@ComponentScan` takes the package of the annotated class as default package to scan, which in this e.g. is `com.example.demo`.
Also you don't need to add `@ComponentScan` if you are not giving array of packages because `@SpringBootApplication` already has that inside it.

Comment: @k1eran can you give more information on your project structure/package?
Because what I think you are saying is not possible. maybe frame your question in a different way!

Comment: I added more details on 'works'  @terry

Comment: I added more on project structure/package @sanjay-rawat

Answer (score 0):

With the errors you posted i can see you do have Autowire problem in both the case.

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.foo.Foo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`
is there in both case.

Now to answer you question:

`@ComponentScan` takes the package of the annotated class as default package to scan, which in this e.g. is `com.example.demo`. So spring is only scanning `com.example.demo` and would scan any sub-package i.e. `com.example.demo.blah`

If you want an easy solution where you don't want to get into pain of managing `ComponentScan` by yourself consider structuring your code as suggested in [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html).

If you want to continue with current structure try this on main method of `DemoApplication.java`:

`@ComponentScan({"com.bar", "com.example.demo", "com.foo"})`

Likewise, in future if you have another package say `com.one.more.pack` then you would have to add that in ComponentScan like this
`@ComponentScan({"com.bar", "com.example.demo", "com.foo", "com.one.more.pack"})`